# StreamReader throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, streamreader

I am having some difficulty getting a segment of code working. Here is the narrative: I have multiple text files that have specific formatting (since they are code-generated) that I need to extract specific blocks of text and display only those blocks of text in a textbox. For example, one such block would be "STN COMMENT"  "END COMMENT". This file could have two, three, or even 10 such blocks, and will have different types of blocks, where COMMENT would be replaced with QUESTION, ANNOUNCEMENT, or TRAFFIC. All end with the corresponding "END ". Here is the first code segment I tried:

```
'block to parse only this user's announcements
'dl is variable alias for: Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
txtNetLog.Text = "" 'clears the textbox
TmpFileName = logPath + ByCall + "-" + Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy") + ".tmp" 'sets filename with path defined in module
Try
    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(TmpFileName)
    Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
        While Not (line Is Nothing)
            line = sr.ReadLine()
            If line.Contains("STN ANNOUNCEMENT") Then '***This is line 238 from exception
                Do
                    txtNetLog.Text = txtNetLog.Text & line + dl
                    line = sr.ReadLine()
                Loop Until line.Contains("END ANNOUNCEMENT")
             End If
         End While
     End Using
 Catch ex As Exception
     Dim msg As String = "Error: Failure Parsing Temp File For Announcements. Contact Developer" + dl + ex.ToString
     Dim title = "Error in StreamReader"
     Dim errorFile As System.IO.StreamWriter
     Dim errorFileName As String = logPath + "Errors.txt"
     errorFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(errorFileName, True)
     errorFile.Write(msg)
     errorFile.Close()
     MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, title)
 End Try
```

This generated the following exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GSPASEC_Net_Control.ReviewNetLogFrm.ParseLog(Int32 DataType, Int32 SortType) in C:\Users\KE4NHW\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GSPASEC Net Control\GSPASEC Net Control\ReviewNetLogFrm.vb:line 238

I have line 238 marked in the code above. However, here is the output of that block:

STN ANNOUNCEMENT :  18:50:54  KE4NHW

ASDFASDFASDFASDF

STN ANNOUNCEMENT :  18:50:57  KE4NHW

DFADFADFASWERASDF

STN ANNOUNCEMENT :  18:51:01  KE4NHW

GHSDETGJNHSDFAW34ASDFG

This output is missing the "END ANNOUNCEMENT" line that should be put in the textbox, but otherwise it does get all of the announcements. It misses one line per text block (the end line) and throws that nullreferenceexception; other than that if I can get the end statement to display then at least we'll have all the text that needs to be pulled.

I have also tried the following changes with no success, all produce the same error:

Changed the While Not (line Is Nothing)...End While to Do...Loop Until line Is Nothing

Changed that to Do Until line Is Nothing...Loop

My latest tested version is this:

```
    txtNetLog.Text = ""
    'block to parse only this user's Comments
    TmpFileName = logPath + ByCall + "-" + Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy") + ".tmp"
    Try
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(TmpFileName)
            Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
            Do Until line Is Nothing
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                If line.Contains("STN COMMENT") Then
                    Do Until line.Contains("END COMMENT")
                        txtNetLog.Text = txtNetLog.Text + line + nl + nl
                        line = sr.ReadLine()
                    Loop
                End If
            Loop
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim msg As String = "Error: Failure Parsing Temp File For Comments. Contact Developer" + nl + nl + ex.ToString
        Dim title = "Error in StreamReader"
        MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, title)
        ErrorLogWriter("ErrorLog.txt", msg)
    End Try
```

Same thing. Doesn't put "END COMMENT" in the textbox, and throws the same exception. I'm outta ideas short of forcing the try block to just silence the exception but that's gonna surely cause problems. Any idea on this one?

Comment: You arent checking if `line` is nothing after you read in the preceding line.

Comment: Stepping through the code in the debugger would show you the cause of the issue in a few minutes. You should learn to use it.

Comment: You also are not checking the contents of the first line read (`Dim line ....`) so of that line signals the start of one of those blocks, the code will miss it.  If the files being read are small, you could read the whole file in and process it line by line; if they are large, you should probably use StringBuilder for the result...and ditto on the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this will work:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Dim startToken = "STN ANNOUNCEMENT"
Dim endToken = "END ANNOUNCEMENT"
Dim line As String

Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Temp\LogData.Txt")

    Do Until sr.EndOfStream
        line = sr.ReadLine
        If line.StartsWith(startToken) Then
            sb.AppendLine(line)
            Do Until sr.EndOfStream OrElse line.StartsWith(endToken)
                line = sr.ReadLine
                sb.AppendLine(line)
            Loop
        End If
    Loop

End Using

tbLog.Text = sb.ToString
```

[Sample data used](http://pastebin.com/6FF3Cuai)

I dont know what the likelihood of malformed blocks is, but I might simply look for "END" as the `endToken` so that the end of any type of block will stop the capture.  It gives it a chance of resynching.

Or the end-of-block signal could include the start of *any* block. In that case you could manually add an "END ANNOUNCEMENT" for uniformity or something else to note a malformed block was detected. The content of those may include non-ANNOUCEMENT data.

Also, it uses a `StringBuilder` instead of messing with a UI control endlessly.  Strings are immutable, so appending to a Text property means rebuilding it over and over.  This should speed it up when the lines captured gets beyond a certain point.

Comment: The solution you gave here works perfectly! I did have to tweak it a little such as adding an Environment.NewLine in the string builder append, but other than that flawless! My reputation isn't up high enough since I'm not yet skilled enough to answer other people's questions, but if it were I'd certainly upvote this one. If someone else can upvote this one please do as it's an excellent solution. thanks so much Plutonix and everyone who helped me with this one! Grr text parsing is a pain. I thought for a minute I was gonna have to break out or imports Regex...

Comment: This also works:
`Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(TmpFileName)
           Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
           Do
                 If line.Contains("STN COMMENT") Then
                       Do
                             txtNetLog.Text = txtNetLog.Text + nl + line
                             line = sr.ReadLine()
                       Loop Until line.Contains("END COMMENT")
                        txtNetLog.Text = txtNetLog.Text + nl
                    End If
                line = sr.ReadLine
            Loop Until line Is Nothing
   End Using`

Comment: Sorry I'm assuming you'd know where to put the line breaks if not I can use ; to indicate where  they go. That almost works but it's a little off on the newlines which can be tweaked. Seems the whole problem was have a readline()right above the Do...Loop Until line Is Nothing. It caused line.Contains(token) to break because it was attempting to parse Nothing. Wow, it's all about placement. I need to brush up on program logic... thanks everyone for helping me, it's working now!!!

Comment: Using StringBuilder adding a NewLine isnt needed - each AppendLine does that for you.  If this works, then please click the checkmark next to the answer.  It moves this off the UnAnswered list, helps others find good answers and shows others you participate in the process.

Comment: there we go, got the check mark in there. The only reason I added the additional newline was to give a little more breathing room between the blocks of text when they are displayed on the screen for the user. Makes it a bit easier to read. Now that this is working, I may experiment with replacing the standard text box with a rich text box. Main thing is that the text box is only writable by the program and only readable by the user. Same way I avoid malformed blocks: only the program makes the entries; this way I can be specific with my start and end tokens.